# How can Google Fiber make a difference since most of the mediating wires out there are copper?

Tags: internet, data-rate

Optic fiber sends more data more quickly. But if you look at the [Google Fiber map](https://broadbandnow.com/Google-Fiber) you will see that only the local connections are optic. The rest of the world is almost entirely copper, right? So won’t the slowest medium determine the overall rate of transmission? What good is it to speed the rate from my house to the telephone pole outside, or to a handful of switches, if these are all linked copper-wise?

Comment: I think it's that even though the road right in front of your driveway is not a highway, you still save time taking the highway. Not to mention you don't share the road in front of your house with too many people, but you share the highway with a lot of people and so you wouldn't want that more public part of the road to be slow.

Comment: I think you can't see all the long haul fiber bundles

Answer (score 0):

Because all global and most local infrastructure has a fiberoptic backbone these days. If fiberoptics is available in your neighborhood there will be a fiberoptic connection all the way "to the web".

A copper infrastructure just doesn't provide the bandwidth.

(And by the way, the link provided does not resolve in Europe, at least not for me)

Answer (score 0):

This map only shows you where google fiber is connected to the end user. The backbone (that is, the net that connects all the big infrastructure, is all fiber optics for a long time already. The big trafic on the backbone would not be possible with copper cables).
Only the *last mile*, from the big boxes of the service provider to the individual households, is in many places still copper wire. And the connections on this last mile is what is replaced now with fiber optics as well.